# More Pythonic Way to Merge a list of dictionaries into one?

Tags: python, django

Is there a more Pythonic way to do this? I know there must be.

```
for form in forms:
   d[form.keys()[0]] = form.values()[0]
```

Thanks!

Comment: doing `for (key,val) in forms:` is more pythonic, too

Comment: Maybe he only want's the first key? But that doesn't make sense because the dictionary is not ordered unless it's an OrderedDict

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want `d` to have all the key-value pairs of the dictionaries in `forms`:

```
for form in forms:
    d.update(form)
```

Comment: You were absolutely right about the update(*forms) not working - I was looking at the set.update docs by accident. +1.

Comment: --> [d.update(form) for form in forms] <-- is actually more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

```
reduce(lambda acc,form: dict(acc,**form),forms)
```

PS: I generally use `dict(x,**y)` to merge to dictionaries than `x.update(y)` since most of the time I don't want the changes to be inplace. This doesn't matter in this case though.